# Radon-Nikodym derivatives relationship between two absolutely continuous Borel measures

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $\mu, \nu$ be nonnegative Borel measures and $f, g$ their corresponding Radon-Nikodym derivatives w.r.t. Lebesgue's measure.
$$
\frac{d \mu}{d \lambda} = f, \frac{d \nu}{d \lambda} = g
$$

Suppose
$$
\nu << \mu
$$

What relationship is there then between $f$ and $g$?

I think there must be 
$$f(x) = 0 \implies g(x) = 0 \text{ $\lambda$ a.e.}$$ 
or equivalently if we set $A = \{x: g(x)>0\}, B = \{x: f(x)=0\}$ then
$$
\lambda(A \cap B) = 0
$$

I know that 
$$
\int_{A \cap B}fd \lambda = \int f \mathbb{1}_{A \cap B}d \lambda \leq \int f \mathbb{1}_{B}d \lambda = 0
$$
because $f = 0$ for a.e. x $\in B$.

I think it is not enough to conclude that  $\lambda(A \cap B\}) = 0$ though.

Could anyone finish this in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\ \nu\ll\mu\ $, then $\ \nu\ $ has a Radon-Nikodym derivative, $\ \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\ $, with respect to $\ \mu\ $, which satisfies
$$
\nu(A)=\int_A \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu=\int_A \frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}d\lambda= \int_A \frac{d\nu}{d\mu} fd\lambda
$$
for all Borel sets $\ A\ $.  Therefore, by the uniqueness of the Radon-Nikodym derivative, $\ g = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}f\ \ \lambda$-a.e. Thus,
$$
\lambda\left(\left\{x: g(x)-\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}f>0\right\}\right)=0,
$$
and since
$$
\ A\cap B\subseteq \left\{x: g(x)-\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}f>0\right\}\ ,
$$
it follows that $ \lambda(A\cap B)=0\ $.